# R: attempt to use zero-length variable name in filter.data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm not an R expert at all and am getting this error:

> Error in initialize(...) : attempt to use zero-length variable name
> Calls: %>% ... filter.data.frame -> filter_rows ->  -> initialize -> .Call

With logs, I've narrowed it down to this line of code:

```
qb_stats_all <- subset(qb_stats_all, select = -c(num)) %>% filter(player != 'Player')
```

And here is the full code before that:

```
library(dplyr)
library(htmltab)
    
# Set earliest quarterback draft year
beginning_qb_year <- 1985

# Set most recent quarterback draft year
ending_qb_year <- 2020

# Scrape NFL quarterback career data
url_start <- paste0('https://www.pro-football-reference.com/play-index/psl_finder.cgi?request=1&match=combined&year_min=', beginning_qb_year, '&year_max=2020&season_start=1&season_end=-1&pos%5B%5D=qb&draft_year_min=1936&draft_year_max=2020&draft_slot_min=1&draft_slot_max=500&draft_pick_in_round=pick_overall&conference=any&draft_pos%5B%5D=qb&draft_pos%5B%5D=rb&draft_pos%5B%5D=wr&draft_pos%5B%5D=te&draft_pos%5B%5D=e&draft_pos%5B%5D=t&draft_pos%5B%5D=g&draft_pos%5B%5D=c&draft_pos%5B%5D=ol&draft_pos%5B%5D=dt&draft_pos%5B%5D=de&draft_pos%5B%5D=dl&draft_pos%5B%5D=ilb&draft_pos%5B%5D=olb&draft_pos%5B%5D=lb&draft_pos%5B%5D=cb&draft_pos%5B%5D=s&draft_pos%5B%5D=db&draft_pos%5B%5D=k&draft_pos%5B%5D=p&c5val=1.0&order_by=pass_att&offset=')

offset_seq <- seq(0, 500, 100)
qb_stats_all <- data.frame()

for (url_end in offset_seq) {
  
  print(paste0('Scraping from QB #', url_end, '!'))
  url <- paste0(url_start, url_end)
  data <- htmltab(url, which = 1, rm_nodata_cols = F)
  qb_stats_all <- rbind(qb_stats_all, data)
  
}

# Clean NFL quarterback career data
colnames(qb_stats_all) <- c('num', 'player', 'start_year', 'end_year', 'draft', 'team', 'league', 'g', 'gs', 'cmp', 'att', 'cmp_pct', 'yds', 'td', 'int', 'td_pct', 'int_pct', 'passing_rate', 'sacked', 'sack_yds', 'yards_per_attempt', 'adj_yards_per_attempt', 'adj_net_yards_per_attempt', 'yds_gained_per_game', 'w', 'l', 't')
qb_stats_all <- subset(qb_stats_all, select = -c(num)) %>% filter(player != 'Player')
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error is because of column names with `NA` values. You can either remove them.

```
library(dplyr)
qb_stats_all <- qb_stats_all %>%  
                  select(-num, -(28:32)) %>% 
                  filter(player != 'Player')
```

Or rename them to give them any appropriate column name.

```
names(qb_stats_all)[28:32] <- paste0('col', 1:5)
qb_stats_all <- qb_stats_all %>%  filter(player != 'Player')
```

Answer (score 4):

@BenBolker: Seems like a **dplyr** bug. [I've reported it.](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/6758)

```r
> library(dplyr)
> dd <- data.frame(1:10, rnorm(10), letters[1:10])
> names(dd) <- c("a", "b", NA)
> options(error = recover)
> filter(dd, b > 0)
Error in initialize(...) : attempt to use zero-length variable name

Enter a frame number, or 0 to exit   

1: filter(dd, b > 0)
2: filter.data.frame(dd, b > 0)
3: filter_rows(.data, dots, by)
4: DataMask$new(data, by, "filter", error_call = error_call)
5: initialize(...)

Selection: 4
Called from: initialize(...)
Browse[1]> debugonce(initialize)
Browse[1]> initialize(...)
debugging in: initialize(...)
debug: {
    rows <- by$data$.rows
    if (length(rows) == 0) {
        rows <- new_list_of(list(integer()), ptype = integer())
    }
    private$rows <- rows
    frame <- caller_env(n = 2)
    local_mask(self, frame)
    names_bindings <- chr_unserialise_unicode(names2(data))
    if (anyDuplicated(names_bindings)) {
        abort("Can't transform a data frame with duplicate names.", 
            call = error_call)
    }
    names(data) <- names_bindings
    private$size <- nrow(data)
    private$current_data <- dplyr_new_list(data)
    private$grouped <- by$type == "grouped"
    private$rowwise <- by$type == "rowwise"
    private$chops <- .Call(dplyr_lazy_vec_chop_impl, data, rows, 
        private$grouped, private$rowwise)
    private$mask <- .Call(dplyr_data_masks_setup, private$chops, 
        data, rows)
    private$keys <- group_keys0(by$data)
    private$by_names <- by$names
    private$verb <- verb
}
Browse[4]>
```

`NA` in `names(data)` are replaced with `""` here, due to the (documented!) behaviour of `rlang::names2`:

```r
    names_bindings <- chr_unserialise_unicode(names2(data))
    if (anyDuplicated(names_bindings)) {
        abort("Can't transform a data frame with duplicate names.", 
            call = error_call)
    }
    names(data) <- names_bindings
```

And the error about zero-length variable names is finally thrown here:

```r
    private$chops <- .Call(dplyr_lazy_vec_chop_impl, data, rows, 
        private$grouped, private$rowwise)
```